# SQL Server 2016 max in partition by select statement not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, window-functions

I'm trying to return the min and max datetime for a grouped set via a partition by statement. The min line works but the max is returning the max date of ungrouped results. SQL Server 2016. What am I missing?

```
SELECT 
    [temp_Emp], [temp_EmpID], [temp_Date], [Temp_Start], [Temp_End],
    MIN(Temp_Start) OVER (PARTITION BY temp_EmpID, temp_Date ORDER BY Temp_Start, Temp_End) AS 'Start',
    MAX(Temp_End) OVER (PARTITION BY temp_EmpID, temp_Date ORDER BY Temp_Start, Temp_End) AS 'End'
FROM 
    tmp_startend
```

Result:

```
 temp_EmpID temp_Date   Temp_Start  Temp_End    Start   End
 300    7/08/2017   7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 8:15  7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 8:15
 300    7/08/2017   7/08/2017 8:15  7/08/2017 8:30  7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 8:30
 300    7/08/2017   7/08/2017 9:00  7/08/2017 10:00 7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 10:00
 300    7/08/2017   7/08/2017 9:15  7/08/2017 14:30 7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 14:30
 300    7/08/2017   7/08/2017 9:30  7/08/2017 14:00 7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 14:30
 300    7/08/2017   7/08/2017 10:00 7/08/2017 13:00 7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 14:30
 300    7/08/2017   7/08/2017 10:00 7/08/2017 14:30 7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 14:30
 300    7/08/2017   7/08/2017 14:00 7/08/2017 15:00 7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 15:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave out the `order by`.  That makes the values cumulative:

```
SELECT [temp_Emp], [temp_EmpID],[temp_Date],[Temp_Start],[Temp_End],
       min(Temp_Start) over (partition by temp_EmpID, temp_Date) as [Start],
       max(Temp_End) over (partition by temp_EmpID, temp_Date) as [End]
FROM tmp_startend;
```

The `min()` just happened to work because the `order by` put the smallest value first -- so the cumulative `min()` is the same as the overall `min()`.

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried removing the order but I got an error saying that the partition needed an order, I must have put in the wrong format.